# Using Interop.MODI Throws 0x80040154 Exception

Tags: c#, com, interop, comexception, clsid

I am currently trying to implement the Interop.MODI.dll (From Microsoft Office) to use the Image -> Text features it should Provide.
But when doing

```
var modi = new MODI.DocumentClass();
```

I get:

> "COMException 80040154 with CLSID {40942A6C-1520-4132-BDF8-BDC1F71F547B}".

**What have I tried to solve that problem?**

I registered the DLL using the regasm tool:
-Problem still exists

I tried setting the BuildPlatform to x86:
-Problem still exists

**I use the Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with Windows 7 Professional 64Bit & Have Microsoft Office 2007 installed**

EDIT: **I found the Solution:**

> I needed to install the "MS-Office-Document-Imaging" feature to MS
>   Office to get it working. (Software -> MS Office (rightclick -> edit)
>   -> Add Features -> Microsoft Office Document Imaging)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to check if `Microsoft Office Document Imaging Components` are installed correctly.

You can do that by modifying your Microsoft Office Installation

`Software > Edit Microsoft Office Installation > Add/Remove Components`.
Be sure, that `Office-Tools > Microsoft office Document Imaging` is installed completely!

Furthermore, if you are developing on a 64-bit machine, change your project output from `any CPU` to `x86`

Comment: You are a lifesaver dude it really worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Configure the IIS (Internet Information Server) Application Pool + properties + advanced configuration **option to enable 32-bit** applications to **TRUE**.