# Strange System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException error

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, error-handling, publish

I had a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application that I published and installed on my server, but when I tried to use it sadly gave me this error:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {40942A6C-1520-4132-BDF8-BDC1F71F547B} failed due to the following error:
80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
    at PDFtoDoc.Form1.DoOCR(String FullPath)
    at PDFtoDoc.Form1.CheckFileAndDoOCR(String directoryPath)
    at PDFtoDoc.Form1.timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

This seemed like a ".dll" file missing to me, but I couldn't figure out which one or if this is the real problem. What could cause this? And how do I solve it?

Comment: This answer should cover it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213894/using-interop-modi-throws-0x80040154-exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue of COM Interop. You need to copy manually the dll file to the application or package dll file into installer.

Comment: Well, instead of copying manually, re-installing `Microsoft Image Acquisition Library` solves the problem more safely. thanks for the idea its solved now.