# Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.MODI' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

i have one web application i have hosted it on IIS 7. When i browse the site its giving me following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.MODI' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

**Description:** An unhanded exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

**Exception Details:** System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.MODI' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

i tried several things but nothing working out.please suggest me something relevant.

Comment: It's better to accept below answer as an answer..because the answer is correct and when it is marked as an answer it will help other users.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely 32 vs. 64 bit mismatch. You are likely trying to load 32 bit Microsoft Office native code into 64bit IIS AppPool. To hack it working - try to change AppPool to 32 bit.

See related [Using Interop.MODI Throws 0x80040154 Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213894/using-interop-modi-throws-0x80040154-exception)

Note: using Microsoft Office application/tools on the server is bad idea. Not supported/unlikely to work - enjoy issues at your own risk.

Comment: project perfectly works fine with source code but when i publish and host it over IIS , its giving me an error..should it be the problem u said ?

Comment: @DharaPPatel, if "works fine with source code" means "work when site is hosted in VS Development Server" than yes because it only supports 32bit unlike IIS.